# Spanning a single image across multiple pictureboxes (Visual Basic)

Tags: vba

I don't have any code because I really don't know where to begin on something like this. I am using Visual Basic. I have two picture boxes which are proportioned apart as the screens are on the 3DS. What I want is to be able to open an image file and have that image span across both pictureboxes as one. Just like on the Nintendo 3DS, where the screens are connected. The reason I am doing this is so I can crop the image into two perfect "screens" which will tile vertically together perfectly. I am making a 3DS Theme Cropper. I am sorry that I don't have any code already. I just cannot think of the first thing to begin accomplishing this. I am also sorry if my question isnt good enough. I am not sure what this website is looking for. Grammar? The right wording? I dont know.

here is an rough diagram of what I mean: https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=samplepix.png

Answer (score 1):

play with something like this, but not really a question with no code.

```
Sub threeds()

     Dim p As Picture

    Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures(1)
    p.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = p.Width / 2     
    Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures(2)
    p.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = -(p.Width / 2)          

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some code that seems to work.

```
Private Function CropBitmap(ByRef bmp As Bitmap, ByVal cropX As Integer, ByVal cropY As Integer, ByVal cropWidth As Integer, ByVal cropHeight As Integer) As Bitmap 
    Dim rect As New Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight) 
    Dim cropped As Bitmap = bmp.Clone(rect, bmp.PixelFormat) 
    Return cropped 
End Function  
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
    Dim FN = "full path of the image file"
    Dim bmp As Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(FN) 
    PictureBox1.Image = CropBitmap(bmp, 4, 4, 13, 16) 
End Sub
```